# Possible range for a continuous real-valued function

Tags: functions, continuity

If $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on (0,1), what are the possibilities for the range of f? Give examples for each possibility and prove that your list is complete.

All I know is that the only path-connected subsets of R are arbitrary intervals:
[a,b], (a,b), (a,b], [a,b), (-∞,a), (-∞,a], (a,∞), [a,∞), (-∞,∞)

Comment: And these are exactly all the possibilities you can have. Correct.

Comment: How can a domain of (0,1) have a range of [a,b]?

Comment: Think of sin(x) on $(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Ok. But when it asks to prove that the list is complete, I am unsure about how exactly to do that. Common sense, it makes sense, but I don't know if there is a way to do so rigorously.

Comment: First, try to come up with examples that show that all of these are possible.

Comment: the image of a connected set under a continuous function is connected. The only connected subset of reals are intervals (finite, infinite, open, closed, half-open). For subsets of the real line convex is the same as connected. Convex means with every two points in the set the interval connecting them is also contained in the set.